# Splitting log records for GAE Background Thread Python

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I run a couple of Background Threads in Python on Google App Engine as separate Modules. They each have one main loop and in that they do some work, sleep and then do some more work. The problem I have is that all of their logging ends up in a single "/_ah/background" block in the Logs view, and after a while it becomes impossible to expand that record. Also the most recent log row is on the bottom but that I can live with...

How do I tell the logger (or viewer) to split the record (as if it had gotten a new request)?

Answer (score 0):

You can [use `logging.flush()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logs/functions#flush) to [manually flush log messages](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/#Python_Periodic_logging), and they'll show up in a new log record. You can also configure logging to [automatically flush](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logs/functions#auto_flush) after a given amount of time, data, or log lines.

Comment: I have tried that (if you mean `logservice.flush()`). It flushes the log but unfortunately it is still written within the same log entry